# .NET solution for two apps to restart themselves with different command line parameters

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Two .NET apps run on the same machine simultaneously and are able to communicate with each other. Clicking a button in one app must trigger both apps to restart themselves with different command line parameters. I need a solution which avoids multiple instances of either app and does not rely on hard coded timeouts to wait for apps to close, start etc.

From what I understand, this precludes the use of `Application.Restart()` or having each app launch another instances of itself and then terminating the original instances.

The reason a restart is required is to cause the apps to start in a certain configuration which is determined at app start up and cannot be modified afterward.

Comment: Why can't you launch a second instance of these apps, then shut down the original apps?

Comment: An application cannot simply "start" itself.  Application.Restart() is special functionality.

Comment: `A stops B; A starts B with new parameters for B and also a list of new parameters for A; B starts and sees the new parameters for A thus stopping A; B starts A with the new parameters` Is that what you are asking?

Comment: m-y: I would prefer not to due to possible synchronization issues with the various connections these apps make to other software and hardware devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on DMoses answer, [`Application.StartupPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx) and [`Process.Start(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) should be able to put it together to do the restarts in the order specified.